# Updating deprecated code from CFGregorianDate to CFCalendar or NSCalendar API

Tags: nsdate, swift2

I'm attempting to update my deprecated code:

```
elapsedTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetGregorianDate((totalElapsedTime + totalElapsedTime2), nil)
```

I thought I could simply change my gregorian date to a NSDate and use the dateByAddingTimeInterval as such:

```
 elapsedTime = elapsedTime.dateByAddingTimeInterval((totalElapsedTime + totalElapsedTime2))
```

This code compiles but it crashing due to elapsedTime being nil.

Is there some other method I should be using to replace CFAbsoluteTimeGetGregorianDate. I've been through the NSDate library and making attempts but getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my code into the following and it works like a charm. I couldn't find this on the web so hopefully this will help others.

```
let myTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval((totalElapsedTime + totalElapsedTime2))
let formattedDateString: String =  stringFromTimeInterval(myTimeInterval)
```

and the stringFromTimeInterval function:

```
 func stringFromTimeInterval(interval:NSTimeInterval) -> String {

    let ti = Int(interval)

    let ms = Int((interval % 1) * 100)

    let seconds = ti % 60
    let minutes = (ti / 60) % 60
    let hours = (ti / 3600)

    return String(format: "%0.2d:%0.2d:%0.2d.%0.2d",hours,minutes,seconds,ms)

}
```

Comment: Notice that despite its name, the value of `ms` in the above is _not_ the number of milliseconds, which would be an integer between 0 and 999.  This would normally be a bug, except that `ms` in the above is being computed as one-tenth the number of milliseconds to conform with the `%0.2d` formatting code later on. Because `ms` is otherwise unused, no error occurs in the returned string.